# get_categories listing foreach with children

Tags: categories

My code for loop of categories

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories('hide_empty=1&exclude=1&orderby=slug&order=ASC');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<li class="cat-item cat-item-'.$category->cat_ID.'">';
    echo '<a href="'.site_url().'/category/'.$category->slug.'">';
    echo $category->cat_name;
    echo "</a>";
    echo ' ('.$category->category_count.')';
    echo '</li>';
}
?>
```

Preview the code above:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Category one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CHILDREN OF Category third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category third</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to stay:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Category one</a><span class="description">...</span>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Children primary of Category one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Children second of Category one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Children third of Category one</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Category two</a><span class="description">...</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category third</a><span class="description">...</span>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Children primary of Category third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Children second of Category third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Children third of Category third</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

understand?

Comment: Why not [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)?

Comment: I want to also add the category description.

Comment: Then use a custom Walker with `wp_list_categories()`. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115197/21376

Comment: Thanks bro, it was not my solution, but with this I managed to get the solution, I was in 'category-template.php' and modified it there yourself. grateful for the help.

Comment: No! Do not hack Core Files. That is not a reasonable solution.

Comment: Yes I was told this, then just include extending a class which I wanted

Comment: ^^ I don't know what that comment means ^^